# When deleting a VPC in AWS unable to delete Network interface which is attached to RDSNetworkInterface

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-vpc

I'm trying to "delete VCP" from within AWS.

When doing so it shows me all the resources that need to be removed. After removing them I'm left with a network interface which seems to be connected to RDS as its description is "RDSNetworkInterface". So when attempting to delete/detach it states: "Network interface is currently in use."

Just can't work out how to remove the association it has with RDS, so I can remove it then finally delete the VCP?

Comment: See [I tried to delete my Amazon VPC, but I received a dependency error. How can I delete my Amazon VPC?](https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/troubleshoot-dependency-error-delete-vpc/).

Comment: It sounds like you still have an RDS instance in the VPC which you would need to delete before you can delete the VPC.

Comment: @MarkB but deleting the instance would resolve in me losing the data. Is this the only way around this?

Comment: How do you expect to delete a VPC, while keeping a database that resides inside the VPC? What is the ultimate goal you are trying to accomplish here? Your question is asking how to delete a VPC, but now you are saying you have things inside that VPC you don't want to delete.

Comment: I'm by no means an expert and still don't have a full understanding of how things work, hence me asking a question. So I'd need to make some sort of a clone of the DB delete the one attached then remove the network interface attached to it.

Answer (score 0):

Is the RDSNetworkInterface being used in anyway or attached to any existing resource? Try to describe it and you might get some idea.

Once it is deleted, you should be able to delete vpc as well.

See also: [AWS not able to delete network interface](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70570893/aws-not-able-to-delete-network-interface)

Comment: I assume it's being used by an RDS aurora database but I don't want to delete it to remove that attachment. Surely one can just delete the attachment. Just can't see where that is in RDS UI